# Understanding boundCenterBottom()

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I’m trying to replicate the behavior of `ItemizedOverlay.boundCenterBottom()`, inside of one of my Overlay classes.

I am fairly certain that I can do this using `setBounds()`, but I am utterly lost as to what `setBounds()` is actually doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I found the answer to be

```
mapIcon_ = mapView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_marker_v);

mapIcon_.setBounds(-mapIcon_.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2,
                   -mapIcon.getIntrinsicHeight(), 
                    mapIcon_.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2,
                    0);
```

Comment: Although you are the author of this question and the answer, I believe does not answer the question that was asked and it might be confusing for people looking for information. What `boundCenterBottom()` does is it tells the ItemizedOverlay where the center of the `Drawable` should be, that is the center should be at the bottom of the image. In other words, the center of the `Drawable` in the terms of `ItemizedOverlay` tells at which point the `Drawable` is attached to the map (pivot point).